# Sorting data on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Looking for a bit of help creating a small database for orders.

So currently I'm parsing orders I receive to a order list on google sheets.
I have a few columns like customer name, date, reference number, address, etc.

Trying to have 1 main order sheet with all parsed orders, then have orders sorted by month in separate sheets and removing duplicate order entries.

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried something? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry the question is what formulas or script can I use to sort or copy the information from 1 main order sheet into the corresponding month, by order date column. Im trying to maintain 1 workbook, 1 main order sheet, with 12 sheets/month.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the script in given documentation for removing duplicates:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates?hl=zh-TW

And For sorting of order:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//create object for google spreadsheet.
  var timeSheet= ss.getSheetByName("sheetName");//create object for particuler sheet
  var timeSheetLastRow = timeSheet.getLastRow();
  timeSheet.getRange("A3:BC"+timeSheetLastRow).sort(7);// 7 is column number
```

You can try those things merge code for your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a dummy data that matches your content in Google Sheet.

```
A             | B        | C                | D
-------------------------------------------------------
customer name | date     | reference number | address
ABC           | 1-1-1990 | 00100            | Home Towm
EFG           | 3-2-1991 | 00200            | Farm Towm
HIJ           | 2-3-1990 | 00300            | Your Towm
ABC           | 1-1-1990 | 00100            | Home Towm
```

Let's assume the data above is added manually, and there is another sheet in the same SpreadSheet where sorted & unique data will be added from above sheet.

Formula: `Unique(Sort('Sheet Name'!A:D, sort_column, is_ascending))`
Example: `Unique(Sort('Sheet Name'!A:D, 2, True))`